# How do I play out my players' characters getting nominated as Emerald Magistrates?

Tags: l5r

My L5R players' characters are going to get nominated as Emerald Magistrates.

I assume there is a specific in-universe ceremony for this, but I could not find details about it, at least in the 4th edition core book.

I want to know where the ceremony does take place and what does it looks like.

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen any mention of ceremony to appoint someone as Emerald Magistrate in any book from the third or fourth edition, but it doesn't mean that it passes unnoticed among the samurai caste.

While is mostly politics and favours to appoint someone as Emerald Magistrate, there is one undeniable truth; only the Emperor can appoint a Emerald Magistrate, even the Emerald Champion can only recommend someone to a vacant spot. According to *Winter Court: Kyuden Kakita* there is only one dojo to train Emerald Magistrates, the Ruby Dojo located in the Emerald Champion Castle (Shiro Yogasha).

So, while this doesn't fully answer your question, I would assume that it does have an initiation ceremony for the newly appointed magistrates at the dojo (the location you wanted to know), like every other dojo throughout the Empire.

Answer (score 0):

No special ceremony for becoming an EM has ever been depicted in L5R in any edition.  It's basically just an oath to uphold your duty given to the Emerald (or Ruby) Champion, wherever that happens to be - whether that be at the Ruby Dojo or on a generic battlefield.